# How can we show records even if id is null?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT groups.*
     , roles.rol_display_name
     , users.usr_fname 
FROM  groups, groups_roles, roles, users 
WHERE groups.id = groups_roles.groups_id and 
      roles.id = groups_roles.roles_id and  
      groups.grp_manager_id = users.id
```

In my query if all the `AND` conditions are true then only it will show all the records but my requirement is even if `manager.id is null` it should show all the records with `users.usr_fname` as null.

Comment: This is part of the reason why we discourage comma-style joins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `left join` instead of `inner join` (implicit or otherwise) when you join `users` table:

```
SELECT g.*
     , r.rol_display_name
     , u.usr_fname 
FROM  groups g
JOIN groups_roles gr on g.id = gr.groups_id
JOIN roles r on r.id = gr.roles_id
LEFT JOIN users u on g.grp_manager_id = u.id
```

Comment: roles and groups should be not null ..........null conditions we should check for managerid only

Comment: @mahes: this is the exact reason for using _explicit_ `(inner) join` (lines 5-6) instead of `left join` (line 7)